# How to extract the middle part of a filename in python?

Tags: python, extract, filenames

I have a file name in a similar pattern as such:
"XC47566 - **Tui Parakeet - Brotogeris sanctithomae**.wav"

and I want to extract the bolded portion. What is a way to go about this?

Clarification:
most files have this pattern: XC##### - Bird name - Bird species. However, some files have hyphenated words such as here: XC22087 - Silky-tailed Nightjar - Antrostomus sericocaudatus

Thank you for everyone's help. I am not that familiar with using file extensions and so I really appreciate this

Comment: You should make clear what pattern to expect for all filenames including edge cases.

Comment: Agreed/ though I answered already it would be good to clear about what exactly you want to extract. At the moment I assume: All the text from the first `"-"` till the file suffix, but with one given example this assumption is just guesswork

Comment: Ah okay, to be more clear most files have this pattern: XC##### - Bird name - Bird species. However, some files have hyphenated words such as here: XC22087 - Silky-tailed Nightjar - Antrostomus sericocaudatus

Comment: Do you want to have bird name and bird species in separate variables or is it good enough to have the entire string of bird name and bird species in one variable.

Can the bird species also contain a '-'?

Comment: I would like the entire string of bird name and bird species in one variable. I think I got it by doing: list.append(f.split(' - ')[1] + f.split(' - ')[2]) by putting spaces before and after the dashes! So now it spits out  But now I am just figuring out how to get rid of the .mp3

Comment: best to add your clarifications to the question.

Comment: I think the first suggestion in my answer should do the job, exept you might have other sections added with `" - "` in the filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

filename = "XC47566 - Tui Parakeet - Brotogeris sanctithomae.wav"

os.path.splitext(filename)[0].split("-", 1)[1].strip()
```

gives you `"Tui Parakeet - Brotogeris sanctithomae"`

I added the `strip()` as I assume you're not interested in leading / trailing white spaces.

If you want to split Bird name and Bird species into separate variables and you can ensure, that none of them contains `" - "` (a space followed by a dash followed by a space), then you could do.

```
bird_name, bird_species = os.path.splitext(filename)[0].split(" - ")[1:3]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can split on one character:

```
filename.split('-')[1]
```

will give you `Tui Parakeet`

Comment: This would yield `" Tui Parakeet "` and not `"Tui Parakeet - Brotogeris sanctithomae"` as asked for in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
middle_name = "XC47566 - Tui Parakeet - Brotogeris sanctithomae.wav"[10:-4]
```

Comment: yep this works if the number after XC has always the same number of digits and if all file suffixes have 3 letters.

Need confirmation from the original poster to know whether this is the case.